# excel formula: Copy cells B15:L15 if column (B8:B38) contains specific value/text

Tags: text, copy, cell

I'm struggling here with formulas (needs to be a formula, not macro). It seems very simple but I can't figure it out how.

So the main thing is:
Sheet1
if I have specific text (GZ) in columns B8:B38, I want to replace the rows E8:L8 on Sheet1 with predefined rows B15:L15 that are on the other sheet named Formulas
If this specific text isn't in the columns B8:B38 of Sheet1 than should nothing happen and the columns should be filled manually

Can someone please bring light into the darkness?
tnx in advance

tried with Filter and Replace, but that's not wanted...should be done in "real-time" not after the whole table is filled